# SQL Help with a Select Option

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please let me know if I can make the questions easier to understand, as I could really do with the help...

We have a directory with categories and aliases, and I'm trying to add the ability to create alias *subcategories* that go into *top level categories*, where currently we can only add alias subcategories to other subcategories, which is not what we want.

**For example**, I would like to add the subcategory *'Estate Agents'* to both the main categories *'Home and Garden'* and *'Finance and Mortgages'*.

I am only able to add *'Estate Agents'* however to a subcategory of either, so would like to include the top-level categories in the drop down select option along with the sub-categories. Hope that makes sense!

**The code is posted below and consists of 2 separate files to handle the data.** It is currently requesting the PGID - which is the *Parent Directory GID* - i.e. the top level category.

We want the alias drop down select option to show not just the subcategories (GID) that come under the parent categories (PGID) top-level categories, but also the PGID top-level categoires themselves.

E.g. The select option to consist of all level categories, such as:

- **Home and Garden (PGID)**
- Estate Agents (GID)
- Furniture Suppliers (GID)
- Garden Centres (GID) etc.

Not just:

- Estate Agents (GID)
- Furniture Suppliers (GID)
- Garden Centres (GID)

Please let me know if I can clarify further as it's simple, but difficult to explain!

**AddAlias.asp**

```
<!--#include virtual="/Admin/FranchiseAdmin/DirectorySetup/Aliases/i_Alias.asp"-->
 <%
  objConn.Open strConn
 %>
 <input type="hidden" **name="PGID" value="<% = Request("PGID") %>"** />
  <select>
  <%
  SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM Directories WHERE GID='" & CleanSQLText(Request("PGID")) & "'"
  rsTemp.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  if rsTemp.RecordCount <> 1 then
  FailSystemEvent "AddAlias:  Failed to load Existing Parent"
  Else
  %>
  <option value="<% = rsTemp("GID") %>"><% = rsTemp("DirectoryName") %></option><%
  End if
  rsTemp.Close
  SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM Directories WHERE ParentDirectoryGID IS NOT NULL AND GID <> '" & CleanSQLText(Request("PGID")) & "' ORDER BY DirectoryName"
  rsTemp.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  While Not rsTemp.EOF
  CreateSelectOption rsTemp("GID"), rsTemp("DirectoryName"), CleanSQLText(Request("PGID"))
  rsTemp.MoveNext
  Wend
  rsTemp.Close
  %>
  </select>
 <%
 objConn.Close
 %>
```

**I removed the following in the above code `ParentDirectoryGID IS NOT NULL` where now I can now see Top-Level catgories, but can't save due to an error**

The error is being generated from the include file i_Alias.asp and says: *An error has occured. The Directory GID is invalid*

**Here is the include file code: i_Alias.asp**

```
<%

Dim SQLCommand : SQLCommand = ""
Dim SQLFilter : SQLFilter = ""
Dim objConn : Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rsAlias : Set rsAlias = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Dim rsTemp : Set rsTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Dim strUserError : strUserError = ""

Dim strFranchiseGID
Dim strDirectoryGID

Dim objEditor

Select Case Request.Form("Action")
    Case "AddNew"

        'strFranchiseGID = CleanSQLData(Request.Form("strFranchiseGID"))
        'If strFranchiseGID = "" then strFranchiseGID = Null
        strFranchiseGID = Session("AdminFranchiseGID")

        strDirectoryGID = CleanSQLData(Request.Form("PGID"))
        If strDirectoryGID = "" then 
            strUserError = strUserError & "An error has occured.  The Directory GID is invalid"
        end if

        if strUserError = "" then
            objConn.Open strConn
            SQLCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DirectoryAliases"
            rsAlias.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenKeySet, adLockOptimistic
            rsAlias.AddNew
            rsAlias("FranchiseGID") = strFranchiseGID
            rsAlias("DirectoryGID") = strDirectoryGID
            rsAlias.Update
            rsAlias.Close
            objConn.Close
            'Response.Redirect "Default.asp?PGID=" & Request("PGID")
            ' Redirect to the New Parent Folders
            Response.Redirect "Default.asp?PGID=" & strDirectoryGID
        End if
    Case "Update"
        if Not Session("Role_Franchise_ManageDirectory") = True then
            AccessDenied
        End if
        objConn.Open strConn
        SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM DirectoryAliases WHERE GID = '" & CleanSQLData(Request.Form("GID")) & "'"
        rsAlias.Open SQLCommand, objConn, adOpenKeySet, adLockOptimistic
        if rsAlias.RecordCount <> 1 then
            FailSystemEvent "EditAlias Update failed - could not load unique record"
            rsAlias.Close
            objConn.Close
            Response.End
        End if
        'strFranchiseGID = CleanSQLData(Request.Form("strFranchiseGID"))
        'If strFranchiseGID = "" then strFranchiseGID = Null
        strFranchiseGID = Session("AdminFranchiseGID")
        rsAlias("FranchiseGID") = strFranchiseGID

        strDirectoryGID = CleanSQLData(Request.Form("PGID"))
        If strDirectoryGID = "" then 
            strUserError = strUserError & "An error occured.  The Directory GID is invalid"
        else
            rsAlias("DirectoryGID") = strDirectoryGID
        End if
        rsAlias.Update
        rsAlias.Close
        objConn.Close
        if strUserError = "" then
            Response.Redirect "Default.asp?PGID=" & Request("PGID")
        end if
    Case "Delete"
        if Not Session("Role_Franchise_ManageDirectory") = True then
            AccessDenied
        End if
        SQLCommand = "DELETE DirectoryAliases WHERE GID = '" & CleanSQLText(Request.Form("GID")) & "'"
        objConn.Open strConn
        objConn.Execute SQLCommand
        objConn.Close
End Select
%>
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Presumably the ParentDirectoryGID is null for top-level ParentDirectories? Could you set this to a root GID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but could you do this with a `UNION` i.e.

assuming you have Table A with columns desc and PGID, and Table B with cols desc, GID and PGID

```
select * from
(
select desc, GID as X from A
union all
select desc, PGID as X from B
) both_tables_unioned
order by X, desc
```

so if Table A contains:

```
desc     GID
----     ---
A        1
B        2
```

and B contains:

```
desc     PGID
----     ----
AA       1
AB       1
BA       2
BB       2
```

you should get

```
A       1 
AA      1 
AB      1 
B       1 
BA      1 
BB      1
```

as a result

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe the table structure a bit more?

It looks to be a parent child relationship 
So: 
Directory table 
has primary key GID, 
has foreign key ParentDirectoryGID to directory.GID

Sample Data:

- GID 9   - Home & Garden (GID) ParentDirectoryGID=NULL
- GID 10  - Estate Agents (GID) ParentDirectoryGID= 9
- GID 11  - Furniture Suppliers (GID) ParentDirectoryGID=9
- GID 12  - Garden Centres (GID) etc. ParentDirectoryGID=9

What you're wanting to do is populate a drop down consisting of the parent and all its descendants (what about children of children?)

If correct, you may want to look at hierarchical queries  in oracle Connect By Prior (but I dont' know what Database engine your using)